# How to add Field value to a array that shows row by row

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am trying to read Field value and push each field value to Field array. Also reset the Field input to null after adding the value. How to read the Field value and display at "remove" button. I have used field.firstname. Please refer below link

```
const renderMembers = ({fields}) => (
    <div>
    <h2>Members</h2>
    <Field name="firstName" component='input' type='text' />
    <button onClick={() => fields.push({--add Field value here and push to array---})}>add</button><br />
      {fields.map((field, idx) => (
        <div key={idx}>
         --display added value here---
            <button onClick={() => fields.remove(idx)}>remove</button><br />
        </div>
    ))}
    </div>
)

const Form = () => (
  <FieldArray name='members' component={renderMembers} />

)

const MyForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'foo',
  initialValues: {
    members: [
        {}
    ]
  }
})(Form)
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Mahaboob/75rh036o/7/

Comment: Please add code as a part of the question instead of on an external site

Comment: HI Alistra added code, pls check

Answer (score 0):

I am able to concat the values in to an single array, Now I am trying to push the values to multidimensional array.

```
class CustomerTable extends Component{
constructor(props){
super(props)
this.state={
contact:[{"name":"Name0","number":12344}],
user:''
}
}

addTask(){
var sel=document.getElementById('scripts');
this.setState({
contact:this.state.contact.concat([this.refs.customer.value,sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text])
})
}
onChange(event){
this.setState({user:event.target.value})
}

render(){
retrun(
<div>
<select id="scripts" ref="customer" name="contact" onChange={this.onChange}>
    <option value="number1">Name1</option>
    <option value="number2">Name2</option>
    <option value="number3">Name3</option>
</select>
</div>
)
}
}
---Displaying the data-----
<div>
    {this.state.contact.map((user,taskIndex)=>
    <ul key={taskIndex}>
        <li>{user}</li>
        <li><Button onClick={this.deleteTask.bind(this)} value={taskIndex}>Del</Button></li>
    </ul>
    )}
</div>
```